# Http response header: generation time

Tags: http

I would like to know if there is a **relevant http response header for the 'server generation time'** ?

- a delta time in ms : time taken between query reception and response send.

Following this [wp page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) I was unable to find it..

for example : 'X-Generation-time' ?

Answer (score 0):

There are no standardized header fields for that. There are probably plenty of private use names that aren't widely used or understood though. Feel free to make up your own unless you think that you might need something that other software might produce or consume.

Comment: no, sorry my english is maybe responsible. I would like to return a delta time in ms : server time taken between query reception and server response.

Comment: I see. There are no standardized header fields for that.  There are probably plenty of private use names that aren't widely used or understood though.  Feel free to make up your own unless you think that you might need something that other software might produce or consume.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Update your original answer this way I could accept it.